# Where can I find and download emulator of Altair 8800 with Intel 8080 processor for Windows?

Tags: 8080, altair-8800

I would like to look back to the very beginning of personal computer when Paul Allen and Bill Gates started their debut. So I need to find an emulator of the **MIT Altair 8800** with **Intel 8080 processor** inside. Then where can I find and download its emulator for Windows.

I have tried to search over the net, and I found emuStudio-0.39 simulator software. But seems that it is not what I want. I want an emulator that the  front panel's look is very similar to the original as the picture below. Below are two screen capture of the emuStudio-039. It is a Java program.

I want an emulator which I can click to input the command, just exactly like what it done with the true MIT Altair 8800.

[image: Altair 8800 front panel]
*Altair 8800 front panel. [Source](https://www.altair32.com)*

[image: emuStudio-0.39's source code editor]
*emuStudio-0.39's source code editor*

[image: emuStudio-0.39's emulator]
*emuStudio-0.39's emulator*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> [...] So I need to find an emulator of the MIT Altair 8800 with Intel 8080 processor inside. Then where can I find and download its emulator for Windows. I have tried to search over the net [...]

Not sure where you searched. If I just start entering `MITS ALT...` Google already offers to autocomplete with "mits altair 8800 emulator", resulting in a reasonable [list of links](https://www.google.com/search?q=mits%20altair%208800%20emulator) - including the mentioned emuStudio (*1).

The top entry, at least on my screen is [S2Js Altair page](https://s2js.com/altair/). By being a JavaSript teaching site, it's naturally made in JavaScript making it portable to any system with a somewhat up to date browser, not just Windows. Documentation is also made quite well, although not as extensive as the emuStudio.

And behold its [photo realistic appearance](https://s2js.com/altair/sim.html).

And then there is the Emulation-Wiki offering an entry about [Altair emulatons](http://emulation.gametechwiki.com/index.php/Altair_8800).

---

P.S.: And then there's [MAME](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAME) - always a sure bet. In case of non game systems especially the [MESS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi_Emulator_Super_System) sub project.

---

*1 - Which is by the way a quite good site, offering [an incredible detailed introduction](http://www.emustudio.net/docuser/mits_altair_8800/index/) of the Altair and its ecosystem to today's readers.

Comment: Okay. Thank you for the link. I searched "emulator" rather than "simulator". I searched standalone emulator rather than web based simulator. I love this javescript simulator. https://s2js.com/altair/sim.html